# How to Find the Vertical Length of a Scrollable Page in Pixels

Tags: javascript

My website has a bunch of iframes that need sizing. I have been using:

```
x=window.innerWidth;
y=window.innerHeight;
```

Thus I know how many pixels I have to work with and things work great. However, now I'm creating a page that scrolls. I need to know the height of the page in pixels (as in how tall the window would need to be so that the content wouldn't scroll). What would be the simplest way to write this using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.body.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight) should work...